# Stop scroll web page when focus SWF Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have a little problem. Currently I am developing a simple web page with flash games in WordPress.

For example consider this page: http://ggames.eu/2015/11/25/prince-of-persia/

Controllers for this games are arrow keys, when I press key down, or key up - site is getting scrolled and the game becomes inactive.

Is there a possibility of preventing this page scroll? I tried many times using jQuery functions but nothing worked.

Update: I tried this code, but it's not working:

```
jQuery(document).bind('keydown keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode > 36 && e.keyCode < 41) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: set this in the css for body: `body{ overflow: hidden;}` and _I tried many jquery functions but nothing._ well we would like to see the trials if you really do have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with the page scrolling itself because simply your SWF con not catch pressed keys if JavaScript do by the [Nicescroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/) jquery plugin (jquery.nicescroll) which is initialized by your `nicescroll-init.js` script.

So try to disable `nicescroll-init.js` and you will see that your *SWF* is working fine.

And to avoid the problem in that page, you can disable the nicescroll jquery plugin and your SWF will work without any problem.

Hope that can help.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. -1.

Comment: @Jai That's wrong. My post is a good answer and do resolve the problem. Try it before putting comments like this just to down vote answers of others.

Comment: Works great! Thansk a lot :)

Comment: @PeterM You are welcome. You can select my answer as accepted if it was useful for you.

Comment: @Jai I think that's more clear now which of our answers is more useful.

Comment: @akmozo i don't have time to go any third party site to analyze the issue, i guess you got paid for this stuff. goodluck you can edit your answer so that i can remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly stop the scroll either with css:

```
body{ overflow:hidden; }
```

or just stop the `scroll` event:

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

Comment: -1, You've tried just to answer the question ( how to stop page scrolling ), but in reality, that will not resolve the problem.

Comment: And how do you answer it? Instead of suggesting another plugin to use that is simple enough to do in js.

Comment: I'v already put an answer. OP should disable the nicescroll jquery plugin if he want that the SWF can be controlled by arrow keys.